# How to have paginated table from database

Tags: javascript, html, database, reactjs

I've tried a bunch of different React table solutions ([reactable](https://github.com/glittershark/reactable), [griddle](https://github.com/GriddleGriddle/Griddle/) and they all work very similar. You can pass them a set of data and they populate a table. They offer pagination, but not in the since where it's from the source. You can pull 100 Rows from the database, and only show 10 at a time via table pagination. However what if the data is coming from a database / Flux store, how are you supposed to pull what you need from the database?

Comment: It is quite unclear what you really want. Please elaborate.

Comment: Do you want to add pagination for table .

Comment: @Ezhil-UIDeveloper I want to add pagination for a table, but I don't want to pull every object from the database and do it all on the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of a relational database, you would handle the pagination on the database level, if your RDBMS supports it, in the SQL query itself. What you need to do is the following:

- Make an AJAX query to the backend with the pagination settings: *page size* and *page number*
- In the backend, issue your query against the database, using the aforementioned settings, then prepare a JSON result.
- Return the results to the frontend, parse it with `JSON.parse()`, then pass it to the grid component.

In the case of a Flux store, this is a bit more complex as it has different notions than a relational database. The basic principles are the same though, pass parameters to the access component, make a query, return JSON or JavaScript objects.

#### Pagination in RDMSes

For example, in MySQL (MariaDB) you would do the pagination with the `LIMIT` qualifier:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 20,10
```

The first parameter sets the first record fetched, the second limits the maximum results. So in this example case, the records between the 20th and 29th are fetched.

Other databases work differently as there is no standard way of doing this. You should look up the documentation of your RDMS.